# Google Drive API Add, then Remove Permissions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a folder structure on Google Drive that I am trying to use Google Apps Script, calling Drive API v2, to share with external users. Sometimes they have Google accounts, but sometimes they are "visitors" so I need to use Drive.Permissions.insert to give them secure access.

The problem is that I don't want to share all of the subfolders, just a handful. And, of course, sharing the "root" folder is recursive of the other folders. So, I'm trying to remove some of the permissions that I grant. I obviously can't do that without using the API (it seems that permissions granted by API have to be revoked by API or by using the GUI, the latter of which I am not doing). I just can't find an elegant way to get the permission id of the permission that I just inserted.

Here is my code:

```
function shareFolders() {
  var email = "sample@email.com"
  var searchTerm = "FileNumber####";
  var filenoFolders = DriveApp.searchFolders("title contains '"+searchTerm.replace("'","\'")+"' and trashed = false and hidden = false");
  var filenoFolder = filenoFolders.next();
  var internalDocsFolder = filenoFolder.getFoldersByName("Internal Documents").next();
  var subfolders = internalDocsFolder.getFolders();
  var incomingDocsFolder = internalDocsFolder.getFoldersByName("Disclosure").next().getFoldersByName("Our Client").next().getFoldersByName("Incoming Documents").next()
  var resourceView = {
    "role": "reader",
    "type": "user",
    "value": email
  };
    var resourceEdit = {
    "role": "writer",
    "type": "user",
    "value": email
  };
  
  //Sharing
  try {
    Drive.Permissions.insert(resourceView, filenoFolder.getId());
    Utilities.sleep(3000);
    while (subfolders.hasNext()){
      var subfolder = subfolders.next()
      if (subfolder.getName() == "Disclosure" || subfolder.getName() == "Court Documents" || subfolder.getName() == "Searches") {
        console.log(subfolder.getName() + " - No Viewership Change Required");
      }
      else {
        console.log(subfolder.getName() + " - Removing Viewer");
        Drive.Permissions.delete(subfolder.getId(), resourceView); //This Doesn't Work
      }
    };
    Utilities.sleep(3000);
    Drive.Permissions.insert(resourceEdit, incomingDocsFolder.getId());
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log("Error Caught: " + e)
  };
};
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: @Databoy2k Could you explain why you insert a sharing permission to the `filenoFolder` folder, then after `3000` milliseconds, you remove it? Apparently, you're the only one who can only understand your script's logic as we can only speculate. Please elaborate your code for better understanding & for your question to get a good answer.

Comment: Whoops; thanks. That was a bad copy/paste. I've removed the first Drive.Permissions.remove(filenoFolder...).

What I'm trying to do is remove permissions that are inherited by the child folders to fileNoFolder/"Internal Documents". The Drive.Permissions.Insert adds a permission to all of the subfolders and I need to remove it. I don't understand how to use Drive.Permissions.remove when I don't have the Permission ID. Can I not get it from Drive.Permissions.insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

> Note: *We do not code for you but you could review the sample tweaked script below as a reference to guide you in your actual project. I have added comments on the script for more context.*

To be able to remove a permission using the **permission ID**, you can retrieve this **ID** through the [response being returned by the insert permission call](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions#resource-representations) *(see the `insertPermission` function below)*. The `id` property from that response is actually the **Permission ID**.

In my understanding, here's your desired process based on your comment & on your script:

1. Insert `resourceView` permission into a **Google Drive** folder `Internal Documents`.
2. Remove the inherited `resourceView` permission from the child folders / sub-folders *(that are added in the `noChange` variable)* of the `Internal Documents` folder.
3. Insert `resourceEdit` permission into the folders added in the `incomingFolders` variable.

### Sample Tweaked Script

```
var stat = 0; //Checks if a subfolder contains subfolder inside. 0 means that the subfolder doesn't contain any subfolders, 1 means there are sub folders within a sub folder (multiple nested folder).
var permissionID;
var email = "sample@email.com"
var resourceView = {
  "role": "reader",
  "type": "user",
  "value": email
};

var resourceEdit = {
  "role": "writer",
  "type": "user",
  "value": email
};

//Remove the inherited 'resourceView' permission from these folders.
var noChange = [
  'Disclosure',
  'Court Documents',
  'Searches'
];

//Add 'resourceEdit' permission into these folders.
var incomingFolders = [
  'Our Client',
  'Incoming Documents'
];

function shareFolders() {
  var searchTerm = "FileNumber####";
  var filenoFolders = DriveApp.searchFolders("title contains '" + searchTerm.replace("'", "\'") + "' and trashed = false and hidden = false");

  var folderData = Drive.Children.list(filenoFolders.next().getId())
  var folders = folderData.items;

  //Loop through the contents of the folder & check each sub folders / child folders.
  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    var id = folders[i].id;
    var folder = Drive.Files.get(id);
    //Capture a folder named "Internal Documents", insert a permission & check it's sub folders.
    if (folder.mimeType == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' & folder.title == 'Internal Documents') {
      insertPermission(resourceView, folder); //Inserts permission from "resourceView" into the 'Internal Documents' folder
      viewSubFolders(folder);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Insert permission
 */
function insertPermission(resource, folder) {
  var res = Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, folder.getId());
  permissionID = res.id // store the permission ID to the permsionID variable to be used
  console.log(`Inserted permission to folder "${folder.title}" \nPermission ID: ${permissionID}`);
}

/**
 * Delete permission
 */
function deletePermission(folder, permissionID) {
  Drive.Permissions.remove(folder.id, permissionID);
  console.log(`Removed permission in "${folder.title}"`)
}

/** 
 * View the contents of the folder & specifically check if a sub/child folder exists.
 */
function viewSubFolders(folder) {
  console.log(`> Found \"${folder.title}\" folder...`)
  var folderData = Drive.Children.list(folder.id)
  var files = folderData.items;

  //Find a sub folder
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var id = files[i].id;
    var folder = Drive.Files.get(id);
    //Capture the subfolder & run the script called "Peek"
    if (folder.mimeType == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder') {
      peek(folder) > 0 ? peek(folder) : null
    }
  }

}

/**
 * Review the child folder the
 * */
function peek(folder) {
  console.log(`Sub-folder \"${folder.title}\" found`);

  //Removes "resourceView" permission in 'noChange' variable folders.
  noChange.join('').match(folder.title) ? deletePermission(folder, permissionID) : null;

  //Inserts "resourceEdit" permission to the 'incomingFolders' variable.
  incomingFolders.join(' ').match(folder.title) ? insertPermission(resourceEdit, folder) : null;

  //Captures if current subfolder contains abother subfolder. This will only show in the logs for review in case you want to review (nested sub folders).
  var folderData = Drive.Children.list(folder.id)
  var files = folderData.items;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var id = files[i].id;
    var folder = Drive.Files.get(id);
    if (folder.mimeType == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder') {
      viewSubFolders(folder)
      stat += 1
    } else {
      stat = 0
    }
  }
  return stat;
}
```

### Demo

Test **Internal Documents** Folder & its child folders/files:

> [image]
> [image]

After running the script.

**Internal Documents** with `resourceView` sharing permissions:

> [image]
> [image]

**Child folders / sub-folders** *(added in the `noChange` variable)* did not inherit the `resourceView` sharing permissions from the parent folder *(**Internal Documents** Folder)*:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

**Other child/sub folders** added in the `incomingFolders` have the `resourceEdit` permission:

> [image]
> [image]

The rest of the contents of the **Internal Documents** Folder will inherit the `resourceView` permission.

Sample Execution logs:

> [image]

### References

- [Insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert)
- [Delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/delete)
- [Children: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list)
- [Google Drive MIME types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/mime-types)

Comment: @Databoy2k I hope this helps. Feel free to comment there are any misunderstandings in your post.

Comment: Wow. You absolutely nailed it and just taught me a huge amount of new javascript as well. I don't know if there's enough "thank you" in this response, but THANK YOU.